# How to check count in the list attribute using sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sap-commerce-cloud

There is a attibute named productlist which is of type list which contains many products.

So i want all customers who have just one product in the productlist :

```
customer productlist 

xxxx    12345,
yyyy    12345,67891,
zzzz    101112,52693,89563,
aaaa    12536



Expected Results :

customer productlist 

xxxx    12345,
aaaa    12536
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: @jarlh thanks for the suggestion but as of now it is not possible for me to do so.I wan to take list from the data.

Answer (score 0):

As jarlh said, if posible try to remodel the database.

But to help you in this specific case you can do something using a user defined function and charindex() that would return the number of ',' occuring in the productlist column. This will break execution as it will have to execute once for each row, and have a heavy impact on performance, but it will get the job done.

Looking at the example data you would need to check if there is a product after the first occurence of ','.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example :

```
    DECLARE @TAble TABLE 
                (
                customerName varchar(50),
                productlist  varchar(50) 
                )


                INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('xxxx', '12345')
                INSERT INTO @table VALUES('yyyy', '12345,67891')
                INSERT INTO @table VALUES('zzzz', '101112,52693,89563')
                INSERT INTO @table VALUES('aaaa', '12536')

                SELECT * FROM (
                select customerName,productlist,len(productlist)- len(replace(productlist,',','') )+1 as counts from @TAble

                )  AS t
                WHERE t.counts=1

 Output :
       customerName   productlist   counts
        xxxx             12345       1
        aaaa             12536       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `REPLACE` to compare the length of the original string with the length of the string with all commas removed, and `REGEXP` to cover the case where there's a trailing comma:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE length(productlist) - length(replace(productlist, ',', '')
    - if(productlist REGEXP '.*, *$', 1, 0) /* Handles trailing commas */
    = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this in MySQL and it worked.

Try using

```
select customer,productlist from table_name
where instr(substr(productlist,1,length(productlist)-1),',')=0;
```